# Tomcat shutdown.sh fails with Connection Refused when started as tomcat user instead of root

Tags: linux, tomcat, sudo, shutdown, rhel

I am on Amazon Linux (RHEL equivalent) and starting Tomcat 7 normally as the tomcat user with `sudo -u tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`. Tomcat starts up fine, deploys my application fine and logs the **Server Startup in xxx ms** message to catalina.out. The application also runs fine.

My problem is that I need to shutdown from a build script and running /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh fails due to the fact that the tomcat shutdown listener is not listening on port 8006 (verified with `netstat -a |grep 8006`).

However if I start Tomcat as root:

```
# /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

the shutdown listener is started properly, listens on port 8006, and the shutdown script works as well.

I'm running Tomcat as the tomcat user for security reasons obviously and running as root is not acceptable to me.

In my server.xml I have:

```
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
...
</Server>
```

and there are no other Tomcat instances running on the machine.

Comment: When you start Tomcat as the tomcat user what ports does it use? Try `netstat -anp` and check the pid for the tomcat process.
Also do you get any errors about binding to 8006?

Comment: Also, are you shutting down with `sudo` as the tomcat user as well?

Comment: I'm getting ports 8080 and 8443 used just fine when I start up either as tomcat user or as root and I get all three (8080, 8443 and 8006) when I start as root. Also, whether I try to shutdown as root or as sudo -u tomcat it fails when started as tomcat since there's not a listener on 8006.